# How to pass range variables between subroutines in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pass a range to a subroutine, but its throwing up a "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" error.

In the main I declare and define the range variable I want to use:

```
Sub maintest()

Dim ScheduledSort As Range
Set ScheduledSort = Range("F4:F321")

Call test(ScheduledSort)
End Sub
```

Then in the subroutine test I want it to sort using the range I passed it from the routine above:

```
Sub test(RangeForSort)

Sheets("SheetTest").Select

' Sort in descending order
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetTest").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("RangeForSort"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetTest").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

I think its going wrong at the `Key:=Range("RangeForSort")` but I can't work out why and how to fix it.
What is it I'm doing wrong with the Range and how do I fix it such that I can pass it any Range to sort on?
And if you have a better suggestion for what I'm trying to do, feel free to add!  :-)

Comment: `Key:=RangeForSort`  or ... `Key:=Range(RangeForSort.address)` ...    `RangeForSort` is a range object, not a string. You might also have incorrect worksheet as indicated by Jeeped, but the second version should take care of that.

Comment: You don't need the `maintest()` sub. You could directly pass the range to your `test()` sub.

Comment: `maintest()` is a snippet from a larger piece that calls other routines... In the sub rountine that `test`sub is cut from, I sort on some criteria passed to it from the sub above and then I filter on specific cells.  I need to filter on different criteria and then sort on different columns.  Having a generalised subroutine that did the filter and sort seemed the best way to do that.

Comment: In any case, one of the answers should work. If it does, please select one as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter version would look like this:

```
Sub test(rng As Range)

    ' Sort in descending order
    Worksheets(rng.Parent.Name).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

    With Worksheets(rng.Parent.Name).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
     End With

End Sub
```

To run:

```
Call test(Worksheets("YOUR WORKSHEET NAME").Range("YOUR RANGE")).
```

Comment: I'm currently running this macro from the PERSONAL.XLSB file in excel and run it from there on the appropriate file.  If I start using `ThisWorkbook`won't this stop working?

Comment: Yes, it will. You could delete `ThisWorkbook` completely if you are sure that the name of your range's worksheet is unique in all open Excel workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a **Range** object to the sub, you are passing an object that is already associated with some worksheet.  The sub selects a potentially different worksheet and then has trouble handling the passed range.

If you want to pass a specific block of cells to a sub that needs to change worksheets, then pass a **String** variable instead.

**UNTESTED**

```
Sub maintest()
    Dim ScheduledSort As String
    ScheduledSort = "F4:F321"
    Call test(ScheduledSort)
End Sub

Sub test(RangeForSort As String)
    Sheets("SheetTest").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetTest").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range(RangeForSort), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetTest").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean when you say "ub selects a potentially different worksheet and then has trouble handling the passed range" and this is why in all my subs I code that selects the sheets I want to work on, for example `Sheets("SheetTest").Select` here.  Is this not a good way to work?

Answer (score 1):

I set this up and now I can pass the "ActiveCell/Range" whatever and call the function throughout my project if needed.

```
Public colLetter As Variant

Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1")
Call GetColLet(rng)
End Sub

Public Sub GetColLet(var As Range)
colLetter = Split(var.Address, "$")(1)
MsgBox colLetter
End Sub
```